# @Html.Action na _Shared erro ao enviar uma ViewModel pela Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Na minha `_Shared` tenho uma *PartialView* chamada `_rodape.cshtml` porém agora ela precisará receber um *ViewModel* que terá diversos dados.

Como não quero criar uma *Action* em cada *Controller*, pensei em criar um *Controller* chamado `_Rodape`, e todos os outros *Controller* herdar dessa:

Até rodou, porém não consigo enviar meu *ViewModel*.

Como ficou:
**_Shared**

```
@{Html.RenderAction("_Rodape"); }
```

**HomeController**

```
namespace WmbMVC.Controllers
{
    [VerificarSkin]
    public class HomeController : RodapeController
    {
        private readonly WMBContext db = new WMBContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
```

**RodapeController:**

```
   public class RodapeController : Controller
    {

        public PartialViewResult _Rodape()
        {
            using (WMBContext db = new WMBContext())
            {
                var cliente = db.Clientes.Find(IDC);

                var rodapeVM = new RodapeViewModel
                {
                    Cliente = cliente
                };



                return PartialView("_skin300/_rodape");
            }
        }
    }
```

Quando no `_rodape.cshtml` tento utilizar `@Model.AlgumaCoisa` dá o erro:

> System.NullReferenceException:

Pensei em enviar direto da `_shared` o *ViewModel* para a *Partial*, algo como:

```
   @{Html.RenderAction("_Rodape", new RodapeViewModel()); }
```

Porém preciso de um *controller* para executar diversas lógicas de negócio.
**Como enviar o *ViewModel* para uma *PartialView* dentro de uma *Shared*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira correta de fazer isso é fazendo uma derivação do próprio *Controller*, assim:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{

    public PartialViewResult Rodape()
    {
        using (WMBContext db = new WMBContext())
        {
            var cliente = db.Clientes.Find(IDC);

            var rodapeVM = new RodapeViewModel
            {
                Cliente = cliente
            };

            return PartialView("_skin300/_rodape", rodapeVM); // Altere aqui
        }
    }
}
```

Só isso já basta para que todos os seus *Controllers* conheçam a *Action* `Rodape`.

A chamada em *View* é apenas:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Rodape")
```

Não precisa passar o *ViewModel* porque o *ViewModel* será criado pela *Action* do seu *Controller*. Já existe a criação de um `RodapeViewModel` dentro da sua *Action*. Apenas atente para o retorno, que você está criando um *ViewModel* e não está passando ele para dentro da *Partial*.